# Animate font size change inside textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to **animate the font size** as number of chracter changes inside the textfield.
Use Case: 
I have a textfield, initially i have a large text, as number of chracters increases i want to reduce font size and animate the changes.
Example: In android calculator app expression font size shrinks and animate as expression size grows. 
I want to have such effect.
I'm new to flutter how can i accomplish such effect?
I have already tried using animatedcontainer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "onChanged" property of Textfield. Then check the size of the text inside your textfield. Then do what you want.

Comment: I can change the text size ... But what i want to animate the change in size